# Impact of security of schnorr's identification verifier when reducing the challenge space

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, schnorr-identification

I have been going through some old lecture notes of mine and found this interesting question.

Assuming we reduce the challenge space for the verifier from $\mathbb ℤ_q$ to $\mathbb ℤ_{\log()}$, does security still hold for Schnorr's verifier?

My thought process so far is that it does. While the probability of guessing a challenge is considerably higher, it doesn't necessarily mean that it compromises the security of the verifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what "reducing the challenge space" means. The most direct interpretation of the question is that we consider a normal 3-round Schnorr protocol, with the only modification being that the challenge space is much smaller. Well, guessing a challenge allows the attacker to forge proof. There's already a [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/710/how-to-forge-schnorr-signatures-if-you-can-guess-the-challenge) and corresponding answers.

But let's see if we can get some numbers here based on the information provided in the question. Assuming the verifier has good randomness, the probability of a good guess has a geometric distribution. Consequently, the expected number of guesses to match the challenge is $\log q$. For practical applications, q is about $2^{256}$. So, we expect a good guess in about 178 attempts. This is far from a "cryptographically significant" number.

The sagemath below simulates a forgery attempt. (De)comment the appropriate lines in the while loop, you can get a feel for how long it takes to forge a proof when using either the full or a partial challenge space. Changing the challenge in a round need not be the end of the world. As [the other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/109573/58690) describes, parallel repetition may still make the "effective" challenge space larger while preserving soundness.

```
# Schnorr ID protocol over secp256k1
p = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f
K = GF(p)
a = K(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
b = K(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007)
E = EllipticCurve(K, (a, b))
G = E(0x79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798, 0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8)
E.set_order(0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141 * 0x1)
q = E.order()
Fq = GF(q)
qq = ceil(log(q))
print("qq = {}".format(qq))
# secret dlog value
x = Fq.random_element()
X = x * G
solved = False
counter = 0
while not solved:
   # e = Fq.random_element()
   # e_guess = Fq.random_element()
   e = randint(0, qq)
   e_guess = randint(0, qq)
   solved = (e_guess == e)
   counter += 1
print("Solved in {} iterations".format(counter))
# Forge a a proof of knowledge of the discrete logarithm of X
s = Fq.random_element()
R = s * G - e_guess * X 
assert s * G == R + e * X
print("Forged!")
```

Answer (score 1):

For special-sound $\Sigma$-protocols (such as Schnorr's ID scheme), the challenge length can be changed arbitrarily. E.g. to increase the challenge length from $t$ to $2t$, run the protocol twice in parallel. To decrease the challenge space to $t'<t$, append $t'-t$ zeros to the length $t'$ challenge. For a challenge length $t$, the soundness error (the probability of accepting a false statement) is $2^{-t}$. Details can be found in Ivan Damgård's [lecture notes](http://www.daimi.au.dk/ivan/Sigma.pdf).